# Sqlite Images into Keras training

Tags: python, keras

I have the data for my Keras model stored in a sqlite database. Using the sqlite3 python module I extract the image data into an array. Also in that database is my feature data. I have tried 100 different ways to extract the data and put it into a model that has my images as input and features as output. Is there a guide or something that isn't the wonderfully in depth keras documentation to do so?

Comment: You aren't describing what is the exact problem, you say nothing with "tried 100 ways". Better describe the actual problem you are having.

Comment: I have had a slew of different problems but giving you each error message that propagates up will just lead me to solving a small problem that just leads to another because I am not doing something right at the fundamental level.

Comment: You say that you think that you are not doing something right at the fundamental level, but then there is no evidence of that, or source code to actually help you. What exact answer are you trying to get?

Comment: I know, I pressed enter too early and SO wouldn't let me edit, here is what I was trying to add:

If I want to import image data into a keras model where the input to that model is as such:

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     input_shape=[307, 441, 3]))

And then when fit is called on the model, as such:

model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train...

where x_train is an array of images pulled from my database.

Comment: And if the error message helps:

 Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 100 arrays

Comment: The error just points to you not assembling the inputs correctly, but as we don't have source code, we cannot say much.